# Discard quotes in filepaths when WebStorm refactors them

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I use Sass in my project, and I don't want to use quotes in `@import` statements. Example of my imports is:

`@import ../basefile.sass`

But when WebStorm refactors my file (for instance I can change file name) it adds double quotes to path:

`@import "../basefile-new.sass"`

Is it possible to discard these quotes? May be there are some on-save hooks? Or some settings for refactoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately not:( Please vote for [WEB-21425](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21425)